# JavaFX Tableview EnsureVisible

Tags: tableview, javafx

Can someone point me to a way to implement an ensure visible routine for a javafx tableview?  I've spent a couple hours researching but haven't found anything.  Thanks

Comment: What is an EnsureVisible routine?

Comment: In swing one could call ensure visible to have a specified item visible in the list or table.  What I'm trying to do is to make sure that the selected item in a long table is always visible.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method

```
setTableMenuButtonVisible(boolean value)
//Sets the value of the property tableMenuButtonVisible.
```

here is more information about table view
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html